# How do this question?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

A discrete random variable $X$ can only take the value of 1, 2, 3 and 4, with the probabilities $P(X=1)=P(X=3)$ and $P(X=2)=P(X=4)=2P(X=1)$.

A random sample of size 3 is chosen from $X$ with replacement.

(a) given that $X_1,\ X_2,\text{ and }X_3$ are the three independent random values of $X$, find the probability that exactly one of these values is more than 3. $\left[ans:\dfrac{4}{9}\right]$

(b) find the probability that the sample mean is greater than  $\dfrac{4}{3}$. $\left[ans:\dfrac{209}{216}\right]$

---

I do part (a) like this,

$\Sigma P(X=x)=1$

$P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)=1$

$P(X=1)+2P(X=1)+P(X=1)+2P(X=1)=1$

$6P(X=1)=1$

$P(X=1)=\dfrac{1}{6}$

| $X$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(X=x)$ | $\dfrac{1}{6}$ | $\dfrac{2}{6}$ | $\dfrac{1}{6}$ | $\dfrac{2}{6}$ |

$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{2}{6}+\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^2 \cdot \dfrac{2}{6} \cdot 3!}{2!}=\dfrac{4}{9}$

---

My part (b),

$E(X)=\Sigma xP(X=x)=\dfrac{8}{3}$

$E(X^2)=\Sigma x^2P(X=x)=\dfrac{25}{3}$

$Var(X)=\sigma^2=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=\dfrac{17}{3}$

$\overline X \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\dfrac{8}{3},\dfrac{\dfrac{17}{3}}{3}\right)$

$\overline X \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\dfrac{8}{3},\dfrac{17}{9}\right)$

$P(X>\dfrac{4}{3})=P\left(\dfrac{\overline X-\dfrac{8}{3}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{17}{3}}}>\dfrac{\dfrac{4}{3}-\dfrac{8}{3}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{17}{3}}}\right)$

$=P(Z>-0.5601) $

$=1-P(Z<-0.5601) $

$=1-0.2877 $

$=0.7123 \neq \dfrac{209}{216}$

Can anyone check my work?

Comment: Firstly, in general, three samples are too little to use the normal approximation. Secondly, for this particular problem, you are required to calculate the exact probability. You need to evaluate $\Pr \left( \frac{X_1 + X_2+ X_3}{3} > \frac{4}{3} \right) = \Pr(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 > 4) = 1 - \Pr(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 \leq 4)$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for (a) is correct.  You choosing three events from

| event | probability |
| --- | --- |
| $\{X \le 3 \}$ | $2/3$ |
| $\{X > 3 \}$ | $1/3$ |

You need $2!$ in the denominator as events with two '$\le3$' like $\{X_1\le3, X_2\le3, X_3>3\}$ are double-counted by $3!$.

---

Your error in (b) comes from $\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(E[X], \frac13 \mathrm{Var}(X))$.  Why does the sample mean $\bar{X}$ follow the normal distribution?

As @sudeep5221 points out, the required probability is

$$\begin{aligned}
P(\bar{X} > 4/3) &= P(X_1+X_2+X_3 > 4) \\
&= 1 - P(X_1+X_2+X_3 \le 4) \\
&= 1 - P(X_1=X_2=X_3=1) - P(X_1+X_2+X_3 = 4) \\
&= 1 - (1/6)^3 - 3 \cdot (1/6)^2 (2/6) \\
&= \frac{6^3 - 1 - 3 \cdot 1 \cdot 2}{6^3} \\
&= \frac{209}{216}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Part (a), can I write it like this, $P(X_1\leq3,X_2\leq3,X_1>3)=\dfrac{4}{9}$?
$\tag*{}$ Part (b), is it correct if I write $P(X_1+X_2+X_1=3)$ instead of $P(X_1=X_2=X_1=1)$? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but late reply.  I was busy and offline yesterday.  Note that $\{X_1 \le 3\} \cap \{X_1 > 3\} = \emptyset$.  Perhaps you've made a typo in the 3rd RV.